# Not able to login to mysql docker container with proper credentials

Tags: mysql, docker

Here is my docker-compose file to create mysql container

Though, it really sounds a easy problem but I have tried all possible solutions and than posted it after nothing has worked.

The container is running successfully. Before this the mysql username and pass was different.

After  changing I am having the issue.

I have  totally removed the images  I have removed all running
containers I have removed the volumes made

Still I am not able to login to the running container. Either using root username password  or the created user and pass

```
mysql:
     image: mysql5.6image(comes from ECR)
     container_name: mysqlcont
     restart:always
     environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: some_pass
          MYSQL_DATABASE: databasename
          MYSQL_USER: username
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: some_pass
     volumes:
          - ./sqldata:/var/lib/mysql
```

Error Message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:yes)
```

***It works only when:***

> I have to set new volume, every time I run `docker-compose up` else
>   the user that I am passing via ***environment*** is not working.

Comment: Remember that MySQL has different `GRANT` syntax for *local* users and *remote* users.

Comment: @tadman how do i fix it